# Preview Documents in iframe in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, iframe, paperclip

I am working on a projects in Rails 4 where i have used paperclip attachments.I want the attachement to shown in the show page in an iframe,where i may also scroll it upward and downward.

```html
I have used this in my show page but error is coming.

<iframe src=<%= @selected_resume.avatar.url %> width="600" height="780" style="border: none;">
```

Comment: <iframe src="#{@selected_resume.avatar.url}" style= "width: 600px; height:780px; border: none;">

Comment: same i have written but i am getting error in iframe.Page not found.

Comment: you are using <% %> inside iframe, please remove it

Comment: ok wait let me try

Comment: and do you know how may i run a particular method from a controller at a time specified in schedule.rb file using whenever. I have this using mailer but now i want to schedule a method to be run at a time which i may specify in the file.

Comment: i have applied your code in the show page of selected resume,nut inspite of giving me the pdf in an iframe,whole page is shown in the iframe means full browser window.

Comment: i am getting this if i remove "#" from your code

Comment: The page you were looking for doesn't exist.

You may have mistyped the address or the page may have moved.

If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.

Comment: have you apllied such functionality in any of you application so that you may let me know the correct syntax. And is it also possible to preview word documents in rails???

Comment: dont know why i am unable to display the document in iframe as i am getting the path of pdf if i apply byebug on it.

Comment: I never use iframe

Comment: ok.................